# Laravel resource update and manipulating with inspect Element

Tags: php, laravel

Dear Community of StackOverflow!

I've just came across with manipulating the ID from inspect Element console.

Example, if my form has action: `/tickets/update/2`
Then if I change it with Inspect Element to `/tickets/update/3` for example, then it updates all data you had in `/update/2` to `/update/3`

Is there any way to prevent this?

Best Regards. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent variable manipulation on the browser-side of things. You have to secure your routes. The Laravel manual has a pretty good writeup on [how to get started with authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authentication-quickstart).

You can use [hashids](http://hashids.org/) to obfuscate your identifier variable, but this is **not a security measure**.

What you'll want to do is verify that the end-user making a request actually has access to that resource.

Basic example:

```
function show(int $id): JsonResponse
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $result = Resource::where('user_id', $user->id)
                      ->where('id', $id)
                      ->firstOrFail();

    return Response::json($result);
}
```

Of course this can all be done much more elegantly using middleware, but the principle is basically the same.

Comment: Yes. I've secured routes with permission and authentication middlewares.

One thought i came up is to use hash, instead of integer ID, but it's generation and duplication check is pain in arse...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to perform validation on the input.

The `FormRequest` validation makes this very easy, in particular the `authorize` method which is designed for exactly this.  You just grab the id from the route and make sure the logged in user has permission to modify that id.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation